# Automapper - split one class to array of others

Tags: automapper

I've got two classes. **Values** is a source class. How can I use Automapper to create two-elements array of **Value** classes when **StartValA** and **StartValB** should be first instance od **Value** class and **EndValA** and **EndValB** should be the second instance ? Thanks in advance

```
public class Values
{
    public double StartValA { get; set; }
    public double StartValB { get; set; }

    public double EndValA { get; set; }
    public double EndValB { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public double ValueA { get; set; }
    public double ValueB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How would you do it without AM?

Comment: Hi, 
it would be something like this:  

Value[] values = new Value[2];
values[0] = new Value {ValueA = values.StartValA, ValueB = values.StartValB}; 
values[1] = new Value {ValueA = values.EndValA, ValueB = values.EndValB};

Comment: Write `CreateMap<Values, Value[]>().ConvertUsing(s=>...)` and fill the ellipses with that code. Or do it all by hand if you don't need to use AM.

Comment: Ok, thank yo uvery much